# Instance of 'Future<dynamic>' Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to pass the Json data to the next screen after login.

Get Instance of 'Future' Flutter is displaying in print statement

onPressed()

```
  var Data =  getData(Username,Password);
                 
                 print(Data);
              Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) {
                return ActivePage(jsondata:Data);
              },
            ));
```

getData() print the exact json response

```
      getData(username,password) async {
          Auth auth = Auth();
          var Data = await auth.signup(username, password);
          print(Data);
   
 }
```

Comment: you have two `print(Data)`. Which one printing  `Instance of 'Future' Flutter` ?

Comment: first print statement @JohnJoe

Comment: what is printing for the second print?

Comment: Get the correct data @JohnJoe

Comment: you've to add an ``await`` in here: ``var Data =  await getData(Username,Password);``

Comment: you miss to **return** the Data from your second method.

Comment: Thank you @JohnJoe

Comment: no problem.....

Answer (score 1):

Change your `getData` method to given code below:

```
getData(username,password) async {
    Auth auth = Auth();
    var Data = await auth.signup(username, password);
    print(Data);
    return Data;
 }
```

As I can see, looks like you forget to return `Data` from `getData` method.